# Problem managing multiple modals in the same angular component / context

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I need to manage multiple modals passing custom templates in Angular ..

I created a generic BaseModal class to be inherited from my modal components.

```
export abstract class BaseModal implements OnInit {

    private modalRef: BsModalRef;
    private options: BaseModalOptions;

    protected modalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
    protected title: string;


    protected constructor(protected modalService: BsModalService) 
    {

    }

    ngOnInit() {}


    show(message?: string, redirectTo?: string) {
        if (message === undefined) {
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.modalTemplate, this.options);
        } else {
        // Handles text messages 
        }
    }

    abstract open(options?: any);

    close() {
        this.modalRef.hide();
    }
}
```

So my components extends BaseModal for example:

```
export class ModalComponent extends BaseModal {

    @ViewChild('templateName') protected modalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

}
```

If in my other page components, there are more than one of these "modal" component instances extending BaseModal, when I open one of them, there is a noticeable slow down during opening, the modal opens in about 10-20 seconds!
In console I see there are infinite warnings about violations caused by long  setTimeout calls.
With only one modal in page, no problems..

Anyone with a similar problem?
I would really appreciate any help
Thanks in advance